# Ho to reference javascript files and cs files in master page?

Tags: javascript, master-pages

I have a master page nested in some folders like this: "SitePages/Site.Master"
and I have js files in other folders like: "jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
the folders "SitePages" and "jquery" are in the same root folder so they are sitting one next to the other but not nested.
So I reference the js files in the master age like this:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link  href="../images/favicon.ico"rel="shortcut icon" />
<link href="../jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/global.js"></script>
```

But when I run my web forms I'm getting a js error saying that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
$ is not defined
```

So it look like the js files are not loaded...
I tried this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```

And it didn't work also...

How should I reference them ?

Comment: Open developer tools and check under network (in chrome), the `jquery` file should be red in the list of resources. Press it and check the path and any error messages, will probably give some info about whats wrong (if its a missing file thats the issue, and not that you are trying to use `jquery` before its loaded).

Comment: I know that the files are not missing because I'm just rearranging the files into proper folders...

Comment: Well, the path seems to have gone wrong, cause the file is not loaded. So its worth taking a look to see if the path is correct...